# Initialize another entity during entity initialization (TypeORM)

Tags: postgresql, typeorm, nest

I have an entity Store that stores in itself

```
@Entity('shops')
export class ShopEntity{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @OneToOne(() => ScheduleEntity)
  @JoinColumn()
  schedule: ScheduleEntity;
}
```

I also have a Schedule entity

```
@Entity('schedules')
    export class ScheduleEntity {
      @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
      id: number;
    
      @Column('jsonb')
      monday: DayDto;
    }
```

In the shop entity, I insert such an ordinary thing

```
  @AfterInsert()
  async createDefaultSchedule() {
    const schedule = new ScheduleEntity();
    const initialDay: DayDto = {
      bags: 0,
      enabled: true,
      timeEnd: '16:00',
      timeStart: '15:00',
    };

    schedule.monday = initialDay;

    const scheduleRepo = await Data.getRepository(ScheduleEntity);
    scheduleRepo.save(schedule);
  }
```

But when creating a shop, I get an error:
**EntityMetadataNotFoundError: No metadata for "ScheduleEntity" was found.**

I don’t even know if it’s possible to do it this way, because there are slight doubts about it, so that when creating an entity, I would create another entity in the relationship

Comment: You have a 1:1 for  shop and scheduler , so the schedule must ecsit prior to the shop

Comment: Does your entity exists in the right path as suggested [here](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/1327#issuecomment-382792583)

Comment: @AleemIsiaka yes, yes, it is. Path is right 
  entities: [__dirname + '/**/*.entity{.ts,.js}'],

Comment: @nbk didn't quite understand what you mean

Comment: when you add a foreign key like you did to Schedule, then the schedule must exist prior to the insert of the shop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just like @nbk mentioned your `shops` table has a one-to-one relationship with `schedules` table.

Based on your entity definition, a `ShopEntity` cannot exist without creating its related `ScheduleEntity` because `ShopEntity` has the foreign key constraint (`@JoinColumn()` decorator defines which entity is going to save the foreign key).

To fix this specific issue, you can modify your entities like this:

```js
@Entity('shops')
export class ShopEntity{
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  // Remove `@JoinColumn()` decorator from this entity.
  @OneToOne(() => ScheduleEntity, (schedule) => schedule.shop)
  schedule: ScheduleEntity;
}
```

```js
@Entity('schedules')
export class ScheduleEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;
    
  @Column('jsonb')
  monday: DayDto;

  // Add `@JoinColumn()` decorator to this entity.
  @OneToOne(() => ShopEntity, (shop) => shop.schedule)
  @JoinColumn()
  shop: ShopEntity
}
```

Now your `ShopEntity` can exist without first having a `ScheduleEntity`.

---

However, I believe you don't need to use `@AfterInsert` at all here. You can simply save both entities at once like below:

```js
await shopRepo.save({
  id: 'shopID',
  // Simply add the properties of `ScheduleEntity` inside `ShopEntity` 
  // like this (don't add an `id` for `ScheduleEntity` since it will
  // be done by TypeORM automatically).
  schedule: {
    monday: {
      bags: 0,
      enabled: true,
      timeEnd: '16:00',
      timeStart: '15:00',
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: Do you mean just use the shopRepo in the Post 'create-shop' request and create both the shop entity and the schedule entity at the same time?

Comment: Yes. Because your code tries to do the same but in a different way.

Answer (score 0):

As the @Eranga Heshan said, Indeed, it is better to use entity creation at the time of creating another entity when requesting. What will happen like

```
async createShop = () => {
const shop = await shopRepo.save({...})
await sheduleRepo.save({
shop: shop,
...
})
}
```

But for this you need to configure the oneToOne relationship correctly, and then everything will work ([used the documentation](https://orkhan.gitbook.io/typeorm/docs/one-to-one-relations))